# Avoiding request limits

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, request, webserver

I'm making Windows Phone app in which I could get some data from Riot Games API (League of Legends dev company). It means that I will be sending some requests but there is a limit of those requests. When many users will try to send request app will reach the limit really quick. How to avoid that? On dev forum they said that I should create web server but I don't know how. I have VPS (Linux installed on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Web Server is a Requirement**

So the TLDR is that you will HAVE to make a web server. Why? Under Riot's ToS you need to make sure your API key is secure. If it is stored in a phone app then anyone could just open your source and use your key.

Riot Security Guidelines: https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/credentials-security

> Note that embedding a key in a distributed client application, like a desktop or mobile application, means that your key can be compromised

**How**

So how do you get around this? Well you need a web server. The server acts as a safe place for you to store your key AND it will act as a means for you to implement rate limiting.

Your phone phone app will only have your GUI/interface (making it lighter to run), and each request you preform will hit your server first, which will in turn hit the Riot API. Meaning your key is only used on your server requests to the Riot API. You can use something simple for your web service like PHP or a heavier framework like .NET. Both have many guides, along with a wide range of other languages.

**Tutorials**

A quick Google search turned up a few tutorials, here is one that looked ok: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/mobile-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application

> Note: If you do not own Visual Studio, they have a free "express" version that I recommend and use myself:
>   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

Web server's pretty much all do the same thing as well, so you can look for tutorials on just that for more general information.

Best of luck!